# Counting new entries in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, counting

I'm working on a project where I search for a wifi probe signal (from cellphones etc). It detects every mac address that is around in the wifi sensors radius. This data is then sent from a server to a database, which uses a reporting tool to show statistics. This can be used in stores to study customer behavior.

This is what the data looks like:

[image: Database screenshot]

**ID:** This is straight forward, it's auto increment

`sensorid`: The ID of the sensor used (we use 3 sensors to convert the signal strength in dBm to meters, which then can be calculated to a position on a map)

`time`: Time of entry in unix

`address`: the hased mac address that is detected (hashed for privacy reasons)

`mean` and `max`: Signal strength in dBm

`nr_packets`: number of packets received

`oui`: oui (first 6 characters of mac address)

The thing is, I want to know what entry is new, and what entry already exists. I would then like to display this in a table like the one below.

It should look a little like this:

```
New customer | Existing customer
--------------------------------
*Amount*     | *Amount*
```

P.s If there is any missing info, please comment. I'm new to the forums.

Comment: "I want to create a table, or graph, to show if the customer is a new customer, or an existing one."  This is too vague.  Explain better what you want to do.

Comment: I want to create a table, like the preview above, that shows if an entry is either new, or already existing. I would like to then count these 2 things in a table like the one above. I hope this clears it up, english is not my main language ;)

Comment: Your question doesn't even define what a customer is.

Comment: In this case, a customer is the **address** specified in the screenshot above.

Comment: Create one more table and store there unique users by some parameter like mac adress and create one column here with count. Each time you get user add to count +1, if count = 1 then its new user it was only once here and if count > 1 then it is not new user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have a rather strange kind of defining new and existing. According to what you say, a new customer is one that occurs just once in the table. No matter if today, yesterday or twenty years ago.

Use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY address` to get a count per customer. If it's 1, the customer is "new".

```
select what, count(*)
from
(
  select 
    address, 
    case when count(*) = 1 then 'new' else 'existing' end as what
  from mytable
  group by address
) new_or_old
group by what;
```

Comment: This works. Thanks alot for your effort and good explaination.

Comment: It's not a very good question, but you definitely deserve credit for figuring it out.

Comment: He does. I'm sorry that I didn't make my question clear enough

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

Given your database and question, every customer in the data set is a *new* customer at some point.  Hence, your question is equivalent to:  "How many unique customers do I have" and "How many records".

That is easy:

```
select count(distinct address) as numCustomers, count(*) as numRecords
from t;
```

I'm don't really think that this is what you want, but it is the answer to the question you have asked.

I would suggest that you ask another question, focusing on what data you want to plot.

Comment: This is one step to where I would like to end ;). I'm sorry I am really bad at making questions. I would like to count every new customer, and every existing customer.

Comment: That would mean that whenever a new customer gets a second entry, it will become an existing customer. Meaning that _new_ customer subtracts by 1 and _existing_ customer adds 1

Comment: @S.terKeurs . . . You are looking at the entire table.  With respect to the entire table, every customer is new at some point.  Perhaps the second column should be `count(*) - count(distinct address)`, but that seems a nuance.

Answer (score 0):

I think a couple of sub-queries would give you the answer. `GROUP BY address` for both, but have one only look at count having 1 occurrence for new customers and second field that has more than 1 occurrence for existing customers.

```
    SELECT 
    COUNT((SELECT 
            COUNT(address)
        FROM
            my_table
        GROUP BY address
        HAVING COUNT(address) = 1)) AS `newCustomers`,
    COUNT((SELECT 
            COUNT(address)
        FROM
            my_table
        GROUP BY address
        HAVING COUNT(address) > 1)) AS `existingCustomers`
FROM
    my_table;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. In theory this works but it says that it returns more than 1 row. Why is this?

Comment: if you look at the query carefully you will see it should return 2 columns. each column is a subquery. first one is `newCustomers` and the 2nd column is `existingQuery`

Comment: I get that, but why would it give me an error for this?

Comment: I missed an important part of the query. The group by address part of the query would result in a list of all the addresses being returned. By adding counts of the group addresses you should get the actual result NOTE: that i have wrapped my subqueries in count functions @S.terKeurs

Comment: Weird, it just returns every entry as an existing customer

Comment: I have found the answer. Thanks alot for your effort and exellent eplaination.